# How to get Paytm Merchant id, customer id, channel id and industry type id?

Tags: android, paytm

I implemented paytm in my android app. But i don't know how to get `Merchant id`,`customer id`,`channel id` and `industry type id`.

code for paytm order:

```
     Map<String, String> paramMap = new HashMap<String, String>();

            // these are mandatory parameters
            paramMap.put("REQUEST_TYPE", "DEFAULT");
            paramMap.put("ORDER_ID", String.valueOf(randomInt));
            paramMap.put("MID", "klbGlV59135347348753");
            paramMap.put("CUST_ID", "CUST123");
            paramMap.put("CHANNEL_ID", "WAP");
            paramMap.put("INDUSTRY_TYPE_ID", "Retail");
```

Thanks. Please someone sugggest me to get this done.

Comment: please contact paytm support team , or look at their apis if they provide

Comment: hi @Shanm did you get answer. If yes post answer too.

Comment: Hi, any update on this? i am also not able to implement paytm fully in android app. its loading paytm.com after redirect from checksum generation url. is it customer id issue?

Comment: Did you guys got any info on this?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in paytm [docs](http://paywithpaytm.com/developer/paytm_sdk_doc?target=how-paytm-sdk-works) 
"Note:
The CHANNEL_ID, INDUSTRY_TYPE_ID, MID and WEBSITE will be provided by Paytm upon registration."

These details will be provided by paytm representatives when you verify all your documents.